# Specifying FID column name in shp2pgsql?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, ogr2ogr, shp2pgsql

In `ogr2ogr` I can specify the name of FID column using the option `-lco FID={columnname}` when importing a spatial data in PostGIS database. I am using `shp2pgsql` in case of shapefile and cannot find a way to specify FID column (searched [here](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg)).

Is there an easy way to achieve this or do I have to do some workaround?

*Note: [A ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3033) has been created on this issue.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect we don't support it, however you could try with the -m switch where what follows the -m is the filename consisting of old name and new name.  It might not work though since gid is an autogenerated field name.

If it doesn't feel free to put in a ticket in our ticket tracker
http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/newticket

.  i think it's a fairly easy change for us to make and can probably do it in upcoming PostGIS 2.2

Comment: As I suspect, currently the name is always set to `gid`. If another column already exists with this name, that column is renamed to `__gid`. Am I correct?  This will help me for now. I am also checking the `-m` option you suggested. I am creating a ticket anyway.

Comment: Yes as I recall, I think that is what happens.